# How to SUBSTRING A Nvarchar Value From A Word To Another Word In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, substring

I Need To Read A File Address From A Field Value In A Sql Server I think Use SUBSTRING But SUBSTRING Need To Start Index And Length But In My Field Value Length is Different.

A Example Of My Filed Value

```
     <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Name="_mainBlockBorder" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Canvas Name="_contentCanvas" Margin="1,1,1,1"><Border Width="202.608503937008" Height="205.148346456693"><Image Source="file:///W:/New folder (2)/8/PAYAM.tif" Stretch="Fill" Tag="W:\New folder (2)\8\PAYAM.tif" /></Border></Canvas></Border>
```

And Result I Need: W:\New folder (2)\8\PAYAM.tif From Attribute Tag In Image Html tag.
I Need This Word By Sql Server Query

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text) - CHARINDEX('Tag="', @text) - 4), CHARINDEX('"', RIGHT(@text, LEN(@text) - CHARINDEX('Tag="', @text) - 4 - 1)))
```

Use your actual column name in place of @text.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @j nvarchar(max)

set @j='<Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" Name="_mainBlockBorder" ><Canvas Name="_contentCanvas" Margin="1,1,1,1"><Border Width="202.608503937008" Height="205.148346456693"><Image Source="file:///W:/New folder (2)/8/PAYAM.tif" Stretch="Fill" Tag="W:\New folder (2)\8\PAYAM.tif" /></Border></Canvas></Border>'
Declare @i xml=@j
SELECT 
@i.value('(/Border/Canvas/Border/Image/@Tag)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as TagValue
```